# How to query the SUM of a column twice for two different states with given date range in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, between, self-join

I am using MySQL Database. I have a table called 'membership'. Each Row contain information of  members joined **on a particular date, district and state**. I want to retrieve the sum of `members_joined` in two different columns for **two different states with given date range.**
Let the resultset skip those row if both state doesn't contain data on that date.

Table Definition is :

```
CREATE TABLE membership
(
int int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
state VARCHAR(20),
district VARCHAR(20),
date date
members_joined int, 
PRIMARY KEY (id),
);
```

The Expected ResultSet :

```
DATE       | FIRST_STATE| FIRST_STATE_COUNT | SEC_STATE | SEC_STATE_COUNT   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-01-10 | KA         |   1000            |   MH      | 1200               |
2021-01-09 | KA         |   500             |   MH      | 550                |
2021-01-08 | KA         |   0               |   MH      | 100                |
2021-01-07 | KA         |   50              |   MH      | 0                  |
```

I tried with Self Joining. But getting empty result set.

```
select A.state as FIRST_STATE , sum(A.members_joined) as FIRST_STATE_COUNT, B.state as SEC_STATE , sum(B.members_joined) as SEC_STATE_COUNT
FROM membership A, membership B
WHERE A.state<>B.state and A.state='KA' and B.state='MH'
and A.date BETWEEN '2021-01-10' and '2020-10-07'
and B.date BETWEEN '2021-01-10' and '2020-10-07'
```

Comment: Use common conditional aggregation. (Self-)join not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT date,
       'KA' AS first_state, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN state = 'KA' THEN members_joined ELSE 0 END) AS first_state_count,
       'MH' AS sec_state, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN state = 'MH' THEN members_joined ELSE 0 END) AS sec_state_count
FROM membership
WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-01-10' and '2020-10-07'
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: @ Akina Thank you very much!!! Perfect Query.. Got the result.